# Creating a folder in vbs if the folder doesnt exist

Tags: windows, vbscript, server

So I am working a vbs script, I keep getting error 800a3ee which is an argument error I believe. It is saying that it needs ")" in the line posted. I am hoping  a second eye on this will help me.

The code below creates a folder if a folder doesn't exist in the current file.

```
If Not objFSO.FolderExists(sBackupFolder & iDate) then      
    objFSO.CreateFolder(sBackupFolder & "\" & Instance & "_" iDate)
    objFSO.CopyFolder sSourceFolder, sBackupFolder & "\" & Instance & "_" iDate, OVER_WRITE_FILES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `&` between `"_"` and `iDate`, change it to `... "_" & iDate ...`